# Guetting past reservations from guesty API

Tags: api, rest

I'm retrieving reservations from gusty api, the problem is that it always retrieve future reservations and I need past reservations too.
In the doc https://docs.guesty.com/#search-reservations it says that it uses a default filter like:

```
...
filters: [
  {
    "field": "status",
    "operator": "$in",
    "value": ["confirmed"]
  }, {
    "field": "checkIn",
    "operator":"$gt",
    "context":"now",
    "value":0
  }
]
...
```

but when I try that filter without modifying it the api response is 400 'Filters are invalid'. The documentation is very vague and i dont know how to use filters.
my idea was:

```
filters: [
  {
    "field": "status",
    "operator": "$in",
    "value": ["confirmed"]
  }, {
    "field": "checkIn",
    "operator":"$gt",
    "context":"now",
    "value": "2010-01-01"
  }
]
```

This last idea is not working either
Does anyone know how to retreive past reservations in guesty api?
Or how to format filters correctly

Thanks in advance